# SAP Business Objects - List for every report with its user access right

Tags: crystal-reports, query-builder, audit, business-objects

I'm looking for a way to generate in an excel or csv file a List for every report on Business Objects server with its user access right.

My report should be like: *Folder / Report Name / User or Group Name / Privileges*

Is there any way to generate such report?

Comment: That is a lot to expect to pull out of BusinessObjects. I would recommend using [Query Builder](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/10/11/businessobjects-query-builder-queries/) to retrieve this in pieces; first all Users and Groups and what folders they have access to and secondly all reports in each of those folders. You can run those queries in [CMS Query Builder](http://biclever.com/software/cms-query-builder/) from biclever which will allow you to export the results to Excel unlike the native Query Builder which is archaic and wretched on multiple levels.

Comment: Do you have the end query? That would be a solution for me.

Comment: No. That's why I posted a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The query builder has no export function built in – the best I’ve been able to do with it is to copy and paste to Excel, which can be pretty messy.
Here’s an example of a query that should work for you:
select SI_NAME, SI_OWNER, SI_PROCESSINFO, SI_SCHEDULEINFO from CI_INFOOBJECTS where SI_SCHEDULEINFO.SI_STARTTIME>=’2009.05.16.05.00.00′ and SI_SCHEDULEINFO.SI_STARTTIME<‘2009.05.17.05.00.00’ – would be from midnight on the 16th to midnight on the 17th if you?re in the Central time zone during DST ? the results are in local time
I think the QB was intended as an example of what you can do with the BOE SDK and has pretty limited functionality, but it can give you some very useful information without any .net or java development.